# why is lower triangular matrix not mentioned in the Jordan normal form definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, jordan-normal-form

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) It is written that

> Jordan canonical form is an upper triangualr  matrix  of a particular form called a Jordan matrix representing  a linear operator  on a finite  dimensional vector space  with respect to some basis
> [image]

---

**My confusion** :why is lower triangular matrix not mentioned in the  Jordan normal form definition ?

---

**My thinking** : I can also  construct lower triangular matrix in the same pattern

see the diagram below

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every matrix is simlar to its transponse, so a lower triangular Jordan block would be similar to an upper triangular Jordan block. I recall reading a linear algebra book (I think Serge Lang's) where the Jordan form was lower triangular. It's all a matter of reversing the order of the cyclic (sub-)basis.